# Splitting a variable length delimited string into columns using Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a requirement where in i need to split a comma delimited string into different columns.

This list is of variable length i.e. it can be

```
               a,b,c,d
                 or
               a,b,c,d,e
```

and so on. i.e. the no of delimiters and hence the no of columns are not fixed.

Is there any way to achieve it using a SQL query?

I am using Oracle 11gR2 enterprise edition

Thanks

Vishad

Comment: Is it a main requirement to use plain SQL and not PL/SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. :-(

Comment: Is a valid solution if result set would contain big fixed number of fields, e.g. 150, only partially filled with data in first columns?

Comment: Hmm. Yeah it may be considered a valid solution. However, i am not aware of the maximum no of items that can be there in the comma separated list. Current max is about 178.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are working.

In a table a VARCHAR2 can be up to 4000 charaters. In Oracle 12c it can be 32K - but must be configured by a DBA.

Inside PL/SQL the limit is also up to 32K

Comment: The string length will be less than 4000 characters.